# Remove rows where at least one zero value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my data frame

```
                          Param1                 Param2    datetime
ts                                                                            
1669246574000               6.06                  -1.80  22-24-11 01:36:14 UTC
1669242973000               6.50                  -1.73  22-24-11 00:36:13 UTC
...                          ...                    ...                    ...
1668918964000               6.00                   0.00  22-20-11 06:36:04 UTC
1668915364000               0.00                   1.6   22-20-11 05:36:04 UTC
```

Output with removed zero values

```
                          Param1                 Param2    datetime
ts                                                                            
1669246574000               6.06                  -1.80  22-24-11 01:36:14 UTC
1669242973000               6.50                  -1.73  22-24-11 00:36:13 UTC
```

Comment: Question? Code?

Comment: maybe you can try `df[df['Param2']!= 0.00]`

Comment: I agree that it is duplicate. My fault was that I didn't assign result of operation to `df`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this:

`df[(df != 0).all(1)]`

or

`df[df != 0].dropna()`

Comment: `df[(df != 0).all(1)]` helps, thanks.  My fault was that I didn't assign result of operation to `df`